# Second monitor not fully functioning

Tags: display, windows-8.1, gpu

I recently set up a second monitor, and old Xerox XL370b. What I'm trying to do here is run one monitor off of my graphics card, an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650, and the other off of integrated graphics. I'm able to set up the monitor just fine in Windows 8.1, but it only works briefly upon turning the monitor on. My primary monitor functions just fine while the second is plugged in, but the second doesn't seem to. My first monitor is plugged into a DVI port on my GPU.

So basically, the issue here is: I plug in the monitor and it is detected, but my desktop is only visible for a brief 2-8 seconds before the screen turns black. If I turn the monitor off and back on again, I get the same result over and over.

Here are my specs:
Intel i5-3470 CPU
GeForce GTX 650 GPU
ECS H61H2-M17 motherboard

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Have you tried the monitor on a different computer to see if the monitor is faulty?

Comment: I have, and it work just fine. I've even plugged it into the DVI port on my graphics card (where my primary monitor is plugged into) and it worked fine.